# Prove that : $a_n>0$, Then, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(a_n)$ converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am given the problem: Let $a_n>0$, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(a_n)$ converges.

We have this problem in a homework, and I don't believe it can be true. The statement being biconditional implies that when $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(a_n)$ converges, so too does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, but if we take $a_n=\pi n$ or even $a_n=\pi$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(a_n)$ converges while $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges. Is my thinking incorrect?

Comment: That's right, it's wrong.

Comment: They left out the condition that the terms $a_n \rightarrow 0.$ That may or may not be stated nearby

Comment: No.............

Comment: Unfortunately, I copied this directly from our homework, and even checked the corresponding problem in the book. There is no statement requiring $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: You might take $0<a_n<1$ otherwise this cannot be true. just take $a_n =\pi$

Comment: It's false as stated, but the fact that $\sin x = x + O(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$ implies that it holds with some additional assumptions on the growth of $a_n$.

Answer (score 5):

The statement as given is not true since the series $\sum \pi = \infty$, while $\sum \sin\pi = 0$, but one direction is true.

First note that $0<\sin x< x$ for each $0<x<\pi$. If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Hence there is some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, we have $0<a_n < \pi$. Hence $0<\sin a_n < a_n$ for every $n\ge N$, so that
$$
\sum_{n\ge N}\sin a_n \le \sum_{n\ge N}a_n < \infty,
$$
so $\sum \sin a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 3):

Here in other to make the statement true we assume

$0<a_n<1$ otherwise the statement is heavily fails, with $a_n =n\pi$

> Assume that, $0<a_n<1$ Then using the fact that, for all $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$
>   We have, $$\frac{2}{\pi}|x|\le |\sin x|\le |x|$$
>   the claim follows

Comment: This is what I would have written.  (+1)

Comment: What if $0<a_n<\pi-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\in(0,\pi)$?

Comment: it will still work since the sequence has to tend to zero otherwise both series blow up.

Answer (score 1):

When $x>0$ is close to $0$ you have $x/2 < \sin x < x$ (and only the first of those two inequalities depends on $x$ being close to $0$).

And when $x<0$ is close to $0$ then you have $x < \sin x<x/2.$

So if $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then so does $\sum_n (a_n/2),$ and $\sin a_n$ is squeezed between those.

And if $a_n\to 0,$ then $\sin(a_n)$ is squeezed between $a_n$ and $0.$

The proposition is true of series in which $a_n\to0.$ However, the example you exhibit, in which $\sin(a_n) = 0$ for all $n$ while $a_n\to\infty,$ shows that if you can't say $a_n$ is close to $0$ for all but finitely many $n,$ then you can't draw that conclusion.