# Infinite sum of sine

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I do not know exactly whether this summation $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\sin(x_{n})|$, with $x_{n}$ approaches $0$, cannot be $\infty$ or not.

But I guess it is actually divergent but does not approach $\infty$ like $\lim \sin(n)$. I try to prove it does not go to $\infty$ by definition of limit but still not succeed.

Updated for my trouble:

If a limit diverges, there are 2 cases.

Case 1: the limit approaches infinity, like lim n.

Case 2: the limit is unidentified, like lim sin(n).

So, I just want to verify that that summation above does not always go to infinity. And, yes, I still cannot do it.

Comment: It depends on the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: But doesn't it always go to infinity? If not, I still cannot find an example.

Comment: I mentioned in this post: $x_{n}$ approaches 0.

Comment: It converges if and only if $\sum x_n$ converges.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2520515/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3692982/42969

Comment: Yes, it is from the inequality |sinx| <= x. But the problem I have here is I need it does not go to infinity, and still cannot verify this.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac {\sin {|x_n|}} {|x_n|} \to  1$ so the series converges iff $\sum |x_n|$ converges. An example where it diverges is given by $x_n=\frac  1n$. [Note that $|\sin (x_n)|=\sin |x_n|$ at least for large $n$].

An example where it converges is given by $x_n=\frac  1{n^{2}}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer is correct. Why is there a downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, because I do not care about unnecessary things like it. The answer is logically true but does not help for my trouble above. Anyway, thanks

Comment: What exactly is the trouble you are facing? You have expressed your difficulty properly. @VAKK_19

Comment: Prove this summation cannot approach infinity.

Comment: You cannot prove something that is wrong. I have given examples to  show that the series can converge or diverge depending on what $(x_n)$is . @VAKK_19

Comment: You dont understand the problem. If a limit diverges, there are 2 cases.

Case 1: the limit approaches infinity, like lim n.

Case 2: the limit is unidentified, like lim sin(n).

Comment: And I know the limit of the sum is unidentified. But how about go to infinity?

Comment: A series of non-negative terms either increases to $+\infty$ or converges. The infinite sum **always defined**. It cannot oscillate. You keep saying 'the limit approaches infinity' but don't tell us limit of what approaches infinity. @VAKK_19